# How to enable USB debugging in allwinner Android tablet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, usb, libusb

I have issues in connecting an Android tablet for USB debugging on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). It has Android  4.2.2, and it has a custom ROM. I have followed the tutorial from *[Ubuntu: how to connect device for debugging via USB?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1228508)*.

```
karthikeyan@spark:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 023: ID 1f3a:1009  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

1f3a is the vendor id. I have added the same in the rules file.

```
#Allwinner 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1F3A", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="karthikeyan"
```

Line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
#mount point for allwinner tablet
mtpfs /media/allwinner fuse user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
```

The device is mounted through [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), and I am able to browse the file system. I just want to know how to enable [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) debugging. USB debugging option is enabled in settings and also install from unknown source option. I tried connecting as a camera device. But the issue is the same.

[ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) doesn't show any device connected.

```
adb devices
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have a similar issue with an Allwinner tablet I have:                     Product ID: 0x1007
  Vendor ID: 0x1f3a
  Version:  2.33